# How to specify any type for a Snowflake SQL UDF

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-function

Snowflake UDFs [require](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-sql.html) specifying the input types. I would like to use a function like `hash`, which can take multiple data types as input. If I try what I would use in BigQuery:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION hash_mod (x any type) returns int AS
$$
hash(x) % 100
$$
;
```

I get the error `SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 28 unexpected 'any'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `variant` as the type:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION hash_mod (x variant) returns int AS
$$
hash(x) % 100
$$
;

select hash_mod(1);
select hash_mod(1.1);
```

Comment: `variant` worked for some types, but choked on timestamps. But this answer led me to try `varchar`, which for some reason worked. Also, apparently snowflake allows multiple dispatch for these UDFs, which provides for more solutions to my problem, though I couldn't find the term anywhere in the doc.